# deploying a rails application on TC server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tomcat, tcserver

ok so here is my problem.

I have a rails application deployed on TC server. I have a .WAR file and the server is able to render data reading through the WEB-INF.

I have something like this on my view

```
  <%=  f.label :username%>
  <%=  f.text_field :password%>
```

Now the view is displayed only when the f.label is commented out and an html tag like

Username

is written instead.

The error says that the stack level is too deep when i use f.label or in fact just a <%= label :something %> for that matter.

Please let me know if iam missing any gem or there is something needed to be done specially for TC server

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to try this:

```
  <%= f.label  :username %>
  <%= f.text_field :password %>
```

instead of

```
  <%=  f.label: username%>
  <%=  f.text_field: password%>
```

Comment: I'm sorry that was just a typo, i was using the same f.label :username. Also, there are more errrors coming. For example for form "<%= form_for :subString_typed, :controller => "deployment_group", :remote=> true, :method => "get", :url => {:action => "show_workflow_list"}, :html => {:id => "subString_form"} do |f| %>" it says the same error "Stack Level too deep"