# jruby -S bundle does not run as it says jruby-openssl gem missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, openssl, jruby

I'm using Jruby 1.6.7 with ruby >1.9. when I run `jruby -S bundle, I see the following error

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.JRuby limited openssl loaded. http://jruby.org/openssl
gem install jruby-openssl for full support.
Unfortunately, a fatal error has occurred. Please see the Bundler
troubleshooting documentation at .... Thanks!
LoadError: OpenSSL::SSL requires the jruby-openssl gem
```

My Gemfile has this open-ssl already

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '3.2.6'
# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'
gem 'activerecord-jdbcsqlite3-adapter'
gem 'activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter', '~>1.4.1'
gem 'jruby-openssl'
```

and here is part of my Gemfile.lock

```
 jdbc-sqlite3 (3.7.2)
    journey (1.0.4)
    jquery-rails (2.0.2)
      railties (>= 3.2.0, < 5.0)
      thor (~> 0.14)
    jruby-jars (1.6.7.2)
    jruby-openssl (0.7.7)
      bouncy-castle-java (>= 1.5.0146.1)
    jruby-pageant (1.1.1-java)
    jruby-rack (1.1.7)
    json (1.7.3-java)
```

Why am I still getting this error saying that open-ssl is missing?
This question is totally related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11940055/deploying-a-rails-application-on-tc-server) and my problem will be solved if I am able to execute `jurby -S bundle` here.

## Update:

The error started after I ran `bundle install --deployment`.

So I ran `bundle install --no-deployment` then `bundle install`, `jurby -S bundle`..everything works fine. I'm not able to understand what is happening here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute `jruby -S gem install jruby-openssl` *before* you run your `bundle` command.